# Working online minimal example of cell-click event in DT not working locally

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Does this example https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-click/

work for you? Online it works as expected, but when copy pasting the code into RStudio clicking on the first col does not seem to have an effect anymore. The pointer does not change its form too.

If the problem is reproducible for you, do you have any ideas why this does not work as expected?

Edit: Latest stable versions of shiny, DT, magrittr are installed

Comment: That doesnt work for me either. You should submit a ticket https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/inst/examples/DT-click/server.R

Comment: Thank you, I filed an issue. Any ideas how to fix it / come up with a workaround?

Comment: Edit: Working with newest devel.